# How can I put a document inside a document with PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Pretty simple question:
How can I put a document inside a document?
Or how can I connect documents to other documents?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need documents to be linked together, you can try [relational-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch) or use [linked documents](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database).

But keep in mind that documents are the smallest atomic unit in PouchDB/CouchDB (e.g. for "transactions"), so you might want to bundle everything up into a single doc, as Sphaso describes.

Comment: Problem is that some documents need to be accessed by multiple documents.  So I probably go with linked Documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is not how noSQL works. Each document has one and one only _id. What you can do is to compose your root document with other documents, but those will have to be managed manually.
E.g.

```
{              
    _id: "ABC",             
    Description: "MyDocument",            
    MyOtherDocument: {              
        id: "justForComfort",              
        Description: "This is my other document"           
    }            
}
```